# configure nginx "image filter" module to take image dimensions from the url

Tags: nginx

How can I configure "Image Filter" module of nginx to get width and height for resize operation from the url? For example,
`http://mysite/img/image600x800.jpg` should return image.jpg resized to 600x800 size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first extract the widht and height, saving the values in a variable like so:

```
location ~ "/img/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).jpg$" {
  set $image $1;
  set $width $2;
  set $height $3;
}
```

you can then add something like `image_filter resize $width $height;` and whatever other directives needed to actually server the file